# puppet 3.8 community - how to install gems for master

Tags: rubygems, puppet

We're looking to use the deep_merge functionality, but the documentation says we need to install the gem through `gem install deep_merge` but also that we need to do a `puppetserver gem install deep_merge`.

Given that we're not running PE so don't have the puppetserver command, how can I install the gem?

Comment: You would still have installed puppetserver in the free version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @matt schuchard - as he said, the puppetserver package hadn't been installed (just puppetmaster and puppet).

Installed that and could now install the gems with the commands:

- `puppetserver gem install deep_merge`
- `gem install deep_merge`